# Categorizing this Thai character using the .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, text, internationalization, thai

I'm trying to parse some Thai text according to the rules explained here http://www.thai-language.com/ref/spacing

Basically, I want to find strings of characters between whitespace and punctuation similar to how we would do in English.  I realise that words themselves are not necessarily split by spaces in Thai, that's OK.

To parse the text I tried simply looping, like

```
while( Char.IsLetterOrDigit(theText[i++]) ) {}
```

to find the next character that isn't a letter or digit.  That works except for certain characters like this one

[image: Thai character]

which is the second character in this word (I think that's the character 'superscripting' the first character in the word).

[image: Thai word]

This character doesn't seem to be categorized as anything by the Char class, ie:

```
Char.IsLowSurrogate((char)3657)
Char.IsPunctuation((char)3657)
Char.IsWhiteSpace((char)3657)
Char.IsSymbol((char)3657)
Char.IsSeparator((char)3657)
Char.IsDigit((char)3657)
Char.IsControl((char)3657)
Char.IsLetter((char)3657)
Char.IsSurrogate((char)3657)
```

all return `false`.

This character might be a 'tone' - how would that be identified using .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Unicode specifications the character is [mai tho](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e49/index.htm) and is in the group “mark, nonspacing (Mn).”

You can use the [`Char.GetUnicodeCategory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getunicodecategory?view=netframework-4.7.2) method to check the type. For non-spacing marks the type is 5, or [UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.unicodecategory?view=netframework-4.7.2)